# Passing Around User Settings in an iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to find the best practice for managing user settings.

Regarding passing data around in iOS it has been discussed many times on SO.
I know these are the possible options,
 - Delegates
 - Segues
 - Notifications
 - Callbacks
 - UserDefaults
 - Singletons
 - Globals

My app calculates values based on users settings. I would like to hear others thoughts on how to share these settings with my various controllers.

Currently the way I have it is through dependency injection, I load my settings via NSKeyedUnarchiver in the AppDelegate and inject it into my tab controller. From there the other view controllers gets the setting via the tab controller.

This method is working very well; however I am trying to upgrade my app to allow various profiles of these settings. This allow users to switch between different "setting profiles".

When a user changes to a different "setting profile", I don't really have a way to update that injected object without adding a bunch of delegates to update the settings class object.

Is there a cleaner and simpler way of doing this? Maybe global settings object?

Comment: If it really is the same object injected in different places, changing the object in one place will change it everywhere.

Comment: Thats what I thought to, It must mean that some where in my code its being copied by value rather than set by reference. Question! If I create a function and pass in my object is it by value or by reference?

Comment: The best thing would be if you could provide your code in your question.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem. Thanks for the thought. Heres my code
car = carGarage[indexpath.row] , basically I think that statement reassigns the whole object and changes the address, it doesnt actually do what I thought it would, which is to copy all the properties from my class that stores an array of cars. 

Is there a special syntax to copy all properties in a class to another class? Or would you just create a method in a class that would just copy all the properties over?

Comment: On second thought... OH WOW I feel so dumb! I totally forgot that ARRAYS are pass by VALUE!! This is why the object wouldn't change...